# Error trying to create customize View.onFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, listeners

I'm trying to customize the View.onFocusChangeListener class as follows:

```
private class myCostBoxFocusListener implements View.onFocusChangeListener {

    public void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {

        //custom stuff here

    }
}
```

And I set the listener using:

```
costBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new myCostBoxFocusListener());
//costBox is an EditText declared and instantiated earlier.
```

However, for creating the class I get the compiler error

```
"View.onFocusChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type"
```

and for setting the listener

```
"The method setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener) in the type 
View is not applicable for the arguments (OCRMain.myCostBoxFocusListener)"
//OCRMain is the name of the class I'm working in.
```

I import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener in my imports, and I really am uncertain why this is happening, as I also create a custom class for EditText.OnEditorActionListener with no errors. I've tried changing my code between View.onFocusChangeListener and EditText.onFocusChangeListener with no change. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project with no change.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to capitalize the first `o` in `View.OnFocusChangeListener` in your class's `implements` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it great when the answers are simple? Thanks to Mike M. for this one; I kept seeing references to "OnFocusChanged" and, frankly, I'm not entirely sure of the difference and when/why one is appropriate vs. the other. And as stated, I also had the capitalization of the first 'o' incorrectly lowercase. But changing it to the following worked:

```
private class myCostBoxFocusListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        //stuff

    }
}
```